# Populating email body through Lotus Notes - Excel VBA

Tags: vba

I currently have a little code segment to pre-populate emails and attaching the current worksheet. What I need to finalize is to also add a standard body, here is my code below;

```
 Sub SDFMail()

Dim name As Variant
Dim subj As Variant

name = InputBox("Please enter name of requestor")
subj = InputBox("Please enter the subject of the service ticket")
dias = InputBox("Please enter the date in the following format DD-MM-YYYY")

    Dim strrecipient As String: strrecipient = "anthonnybelanger@gmail.com"
    Dim strsubject As String: strsubject = subj & " - " & name & " - " & dias

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show arg1:=strrecipient, arg2:=strsubject

End Sub
```

Thank you for your help,

Best,

A

Answer (score 0):

You will not have much of options if you use dialogs. Use the code below so that you can control everything easily.

Copy and paste the code in a module and run it. If this is what you needed, please hit the check mark next to this question ;)

```
 Sub SDFMail()
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim strRecipient As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim subj As String
    Dim dias As String

    Dim outlook As Object
    Dim outlookMail As Object

    'Define outlook object
    Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookMail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

    'Get the info from the user
    name = InputBox("Please enter name of requestor")
    subj = InputBox("Please enter the subject of the service ticket")
    dias = InputBox("Please enter the date in the following format DD-MM-YYYY")

    'Format subject
    strRecipient = "anthonnybelanger@gmail.com"
    strSubject = subj & " - " & name & " - " & dias

    'Save the workbook
    ThisWorkbook.Save

    'populate then New Email attributes
    With outlookMail
        .To = strRecipient
        .CC = "SampleCC@email.com"
        .BCC = "SampleBCC@email.com"
        .Subject = strSubject
        .Body = "This is a default body text."
        .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName
        .Display
    End With

End Sub
```